# Spotify is damaged or incomplete

Tags: macos, spotify

I used to have Spotify but now it says it is damaged or incomplete, and now I can't open it again. How do I fix that?

Comment: Have you tried reinstalling it after deleting the existing damaged /Applications/Spotify.app bundle?

Answer (score 2):

There's [official manual about it](https://support.spotify.com/is/learn-more/faq/#!/article/reinstallation-of-spotify):

> ## Reinstall Spotify
>
> Reinstalling gives the app a new lease of life; fixing many common issues you may be experiencing.
>
> **Note:** Any offline playlists will need to be re-synced once reinstalled.
>
> 1. Click **Spotify** in the menu bar then **Quit Spotify**.
> 2. Open **Finder** then click **Go > Library** in the menu bar. (You may need to
>     hold the **Alt** key if **Library** isn’t visible).
> 3. Open **Caches** and delete the **com.spotify.Client** folder.
> 4. Click the **back** arrow.
> 5. Open **Application Support** and delete the **Spotify** folder.
> 6. [Download](http://www.spotify.com/download) and install Spotify!